# O que acontece com as minhas perguntas se excluir minha conta?

Tags: suporte, stackoverflow

Quando eu excluo minha conta no Stack Overflow, o que acontecem com as minhas respostas? Elas são excluídas? Teria como eu transferi-las para minha conta nova? Se sim, eu posso escolher quais?

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1603/como-fechar-o-usu%C3%A1rio-mas-deixar-as-respostas-e-as-quest%C3%B5es?lq=1

Comment: Se não me engano, tem como pedir para mezclar duas contas...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não creio que seja possível migrar as perguntas/respostas para outra conta, mas as perguntas/respostas continuarão no site, a única diferença é que o autor será um "desconhecido" e não será possível acessar o perfil dele. [Veja essa pergunta aqui como exemplo.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54/erro-r-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: E os comentários das respostas?

Comment: @JoãoPaulo Os comentários também são mantidos, veja na mesma pergunta que linkei, [tem um exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/54/erro-r-cannot-be-resolved#comment58_60).

Comment: Até mesmo o nome que segue o "@"?

Comment: @JoãoPaulo Essa pergunta eu são sei te responder, mas acredito que deva ser substituído por "@user[id]", do mesmo jeito que fica na secção que mostra o autor das perguntas/respostas. Afinal de contas estamos falando de um site da rede Stack Exchange, tudo aqui funciona da melhor maneira possível. xD

Comment: Aqui tem [um comentário que eu deixei para o autor de uma resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16769/#comment31299_16771) antes dele mudar de conta. O nome que ele usava permanece no comment como estava originalmente.